# Equivalence between bipartite undirected graph and arbitrary directed graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let the adjacency matrix of an *undirected bipartite* graph be $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & B \\ B^T & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ where B is called the *biadjacency matrix*.

Now, by instead interpreting B as an *adjacency matrix* of a *not necessarily bipartite (arbitrary) directed* graph, we get a bijection between the bipartite undirected graph (with *bi*adjacency matrix B) and the arbitrary directed graph (with adjacency matrix B).

Does this bijection have a name? Is it discussed somewhere in literature? Thank you!

Comment: This sort of thing comes up often, but I don't know if it has a name. One observation is that the bipartite graph is obtained by taking the direct product (categorical product) of the digraph with K_2.

Comment: Note that it only makes sense if $B$ is square, which eliminates most bipartite graphs.  As Jon writes, it is a common observation but I don't recall a specific name for it.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please refer to literature where such things come up? @JonNoel

Comment: Could you please refer to literature where this common observation appears? @BrendanMcKay

Comment: @root: I take issue with the term "equivalence relation" in this OP. I think what you *mean* is simply 'we get a map $\textsf{UndirectedBipartiteGraphs}$ $\to$ $\textsf{DirectedGraphs}$. I don't see how 'equivalence relation' makes any sense here. On what set should this relation be defined? How should it even be *reflexive*? Would you please clarify and possibly *edit the question accordingly*? Also, saying "non-bipartite" is wrong: this directed graph can *happen* to be bipartite. The correct way to put is "a *not necessarily bipartite directed* graph".

Comment: @PeterHeinig: You're right. I edited the question, replacing "equivalence relation" by "bijection" and "non-bipartite" by "not necessarily bipartite". Thanks!

Comment: Given a bipartite graph, in order to get a directed (not necessarily bipartite) graph from it by this method, one needs to choose a particular bijection between the two parts (not just the fact that $B$ is square). Your description with matrices builds this choice into the ordering of the rows and columns of $B$. If you permute the rows but not the columns, the new $B$ (along with its transpose, as in your $A$) still describes the same bipartite graph but a possibly different directed graph.

Comment: I find it helps not to get too attached to particular definitions of graphs, directed graphs, hypergraphs etc..  Here we just have two ways of thinking about particular sets of ordered pairs, and either might be more or less convenient in any situation depending on what it reminds you about other similar objects that you know.